# Getting compilation error in implementing the conditional operator where method return type is double

Tags: java, conditional-operator

The below code is throwing compilation error please advise how to overcome from this as I have put down the conditional operator in it

```
 Element tetAmount = doc.createElement("tetAmount");
 tetAmount.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(irm.gettetAmount()== null ? "null" : Double.toString(irm.gettetAmount())));
  abcMessage.appendChild(tetAmount);
```

The compilation error that I am getting is in this line specifically

```
  tetAmount.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(irm.gettetAmount()== null ? "null" : Double.toString(irm.gettetAmount())));
```

The compilation error is

> The operator == is undefined for the argument types doubles null

Comment: doubles are not nullable

Comment: What would be your expected behaviour, i.e. what are you trying to test with your condition? `double` is initialized with `0`, but this is also a valid value. You might want to change your method return value to `Double` (the class, note the upper case "d").

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you declare tetAmount type as double. Possible to change it to Double instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think tetAmount is premitive type that's why you are getting compilation fail..

```
double tetAmount; // default value of double is 0.0d not null.
```

null is the default value of object type e.g. Double tetAmount;